# WordPress Translation Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I am running the theme check plugin and came across this warning (below). I have added the text domain so I am not sure what the issue or solution is here?

```
WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain in the file parts/header-pre.php. Function _e, with the arguments 'hr-listings'.

Line  153: <div class='cost'><?php _e('Prices start from: &pound;', 'hr-listings'); ?><?php echo $listing_cost_general; ?></div>
```

Comment: What character set do you use? 
Try to remove &pound; for testing.

Comment: utf-8 I tried removing @pound; but still got the same warning.